# La palabra "alarma" ¿proviene del castellano?

Tags: etimología

La palabra **alarma** está presente en muchos idiomas occidentales.

Suena mucho como "¡Al arma!"

De ahí mi pregunta: ¿Proviene la palabra **alarma** efectivamente del castellano?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. De acuerdo con la RAE la palabra viene del «antiguo» Italiano

> Del it. allarme, y este del ant. all'arme 'a las armas'.

Lo puedes ver aquí https://dle.rae.es/alarma

Comment: ¡Gracias! Por lo menos, tiene casi este mismo sentido en el antiguo italiano…

Answer (score 3):

Anteriormente el DLE indicaba claramente que la etimología de alarma es:

> De *¡al arma!*

Comment: Ciertamente, el DLE indica que se usa "al arma" como una locución "para prevenir a los soldados que tomen prontamente las armas".
Obviamente, en italiano, francés, español... se utilizan o utilizaban expresiones equivalentes, y a saber cuál de ellas es la más antigua.
Asumiendo que "all'arme" (plural, si no me equivoco) sea la más antigua, no veo cómo llegar a "alarma" sin pasar por "al arma".

Answer (score 2):

Por completar [la respuesta de @DGaleano](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/37738/1674), en el diccionario Oxford se indica ese origen común italiano para la voz inglesa

[alarm](https://www.lexico.com/definition/alarm)

> Late Middle English (as an exclamation meaning ‘to arms!’): from Old
> French alarme, **from Italian allarme, from all' arme!** ‘to arms!’.